# Comments with no visible content from no clickable user

Tags: support, status-completed

I received a couple of comments without visible content, and the commenting user is not visible too, nor is it clickable. Here's the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162745/3993662

The comments look like this

[image]

Is this some new kind of spam? How is it possible to leave such a comment? Shouldn't the creation of a account with a username containing only non visible characters be avoided at all?

Answer (score 2):

͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘ –͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘͘

Comment: (U+0358 COMBINING DOT ABOVE RIGHT, U+2013 EN DASH, U+0358 COMBINING DOT ABOVE RIGHT) Translation: "It's been dealt with." I'd translate the comments in question, but language.